# Conditional convergence and the nature of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[I was taking notes from this lecture by Jhevon Smith at NYCC to prepare for my Calculus III course for the winter.](https://youtu.be/qKWLns1YpAM?t=1h11m49s) In the lecture he goes over conditional convergence of infinite sums, in it he states "If an infinite sum is **conditionally convergent** there exists an arrangement by which we can make the sum any real # we choose". I thought that was very profound and the first thing I did was pause the video, starting work on finding an approximation for $sinx$ for a few hours.

I came to this after an hour or so of tooling around in Mathematica:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(2n+2)}=sin(1)$$
[I came to this after watching this lecture by Tadashi Tokieda where he shows the gamma function shows up for the volume of an n-sphere.](https://youtu.be/v425ePq9tyo?t=3m32s)

My question is as follows,

**Is the relation for these functions(gamma and sine) a derivation from that for other functions, where these manifestation are merely the same identity in different forms?**

I know that for the real numbers, they can be shown to be a combination of the other numbers, but does this carry for functions?

If this is a bad question I apologies in advance. I am an undergrad in computer science, if I am asking questions that are above my head I will refrain from posting such questions in the future.

Comment: I don't normally use the gamma function when defining many of the series for known functions, it certainly looks interesting

Comment: @Dan I've been messing around a lot with the Gamma function ever since my Calc 2 teacher forced us on a homework assignment to take the integral, getting it into its final form and seeing Tokieda give that little spiel. It seems geometrically important to me.

Comment: Well it arises through those n dimensional spherical integrals in high energy particle physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the Taylor series (around $0$)for $\sin(1)$, since $\Gamma(2n+2)=(2n+1)!$.

Comment: I guess I should have kept watching the lectures. I have no idea what the Taylor series is yet but I guess its a natural extension of this idea. Thank you. I will leave this topic open for a bit just to see if anyone has anything to add.

Comment: @jakemckenzie  Do you have a question about conditional convergence and rearrangements?

Comment: @jakemckenzie: The taylor series of a general function $f $ is $\sum f^{(n)}(x_0)/n! \cdot (x-x_0)^n $, if $f $ is infinitely differentiable. For certain functions, this series coincides with $f $ itself. This is the case for the sine function and we get $\sin (x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n /(2n+1)! \cdot x^{2n+1} $.